# Select and Foreach in DataSet using LINQ and Lambda are not working

Tags: linq, select, lambda, distinct

I need to do select and foreach but it is not working. How can I do this?

```
Ds ds = new Ds(); //DataSet
Ds.HousesRow houseRow= ds.House.NewHousesRow(); 

houseRow.color= "red";
houseRow.date= new DateTime();
houseRow.description= "ZZZ";

ds.Houses.AddHouseRow(houseRow);

var lHouses= ds.Houses.Select(i => new { i.color, i.description}).OrderBy(i => i).Distinct();

foreach (Ds.HousesRow item in lHouses)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Color: " + item.color + "Description: " + item.description);
}
```

Tks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous type: `Select(i => new { i.color, i.description})`.

You can not cast that type to `Ds.HousesRow` in the foreach.

Change your loop to

```
foreach (var item in lHouses)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Color: " + item.color + "Description: " + item.description);
}
```

And you will be using the anonymous type in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:

- I think using Select() is a little unnecessary since all that is doing is limiting the data sent to the foreach which, at least in this case, would give only a very minor savings in memory with what you are doing. If you were dumping the entire variable out in, lets say, JSON, it would then be beneficial to limit the quantity of data.
- Like the other guy said, using var in the foreach would let you use the anonymous type if you wanted to. My own personal preference is that I try to avoid that except when serializing things (and even then I prefer to do datacontracts to avoid mistakes later if I misspell a word or something)

  ```
  Ds.HouseRow lHouses= ds.Houses.OrderBy(i => i.Description).Distinct();

  foreach (Ds.HouseRow item in lHouses)
  {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Color: " + item.color + "Description: " + item.description);
  }
  ```

EDIT: Also, your orderby has to say something to compare to do the ordering. I did description just for example.

Comment: so what exactly will `OrderBy(i => i)` do?

Comment: Whoops I missed that. It should be OrderBy(i => i.Description) or something like that I would think. I don't have my windows machine with me to test to make sure that works, but it looks like that should sort it by description.

Comment: Now what is your Distinct() supposed to do? I imagine OP wanted to select distinct color and description pairs. Your example eliminates duplicates in the list, which is very different.

Comment: Since there are no primary keys wouldn't removing duplicates just do the same thing? If there are 4 entries talking about a "Red", "Split level" house it would only return one, but if there happened to be several different kinds of red houses it would return a different row for each one. I guess one could be more specific by using DistinctBy and specifying some columns, but I haven't ever used this method so I am not experienced as to its behavior.